# How should I structure bank cards entities into my database?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, algorithm, backend

Good afternoon.

I'm working into a new module about personal finances in an application and in this case, I need to implement a new system to register bank cards that will be used to manage the current user transactions.

The requirement differentiates between **credit** and **debit** cards; where some base fields are repeated and other are different.

Here is the fields for every card type:

- Debit card:
  Code, ownerName, provider, model, initialAmount
- Credit card: Code, ownerName, provider, model, creditLimit, courtDate, PaymentDate

As we see; both shares 4 fields.
My answer is the following:

Should I make two different tables? (one per card type). Or its correct to handle all fields into a unique abstract table called **Card** and provide a new field like *cardType*, which will differentiate the card type and handle the uncommon fields as nullables?

Comment: Why not have a `Card` table with all the common information plus its type, and a `DebitCard` and `CreditCard` table for the specific information for each type. I've worked with some banking systems, and seen the most outrageous solutions to this very problem. There is no one size fits all solution, and once you decide on a design, you'll find it doesn't fit future problems. Generally, you don't want to repeat information though

Comment: I have giant alarm bells going off. Go read https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/faq/#2 and then start learning why everyone who can REALLY wants to outsource card storage to a third party like Braintree. Trust me, this is going to be important.

Comment: To judge a schema, first spell out the queries that you will need to perform.